# How to activate a profile in a maven submodule using a property?

Tags: maven

I am using Maven 3.6.0 and OpenJDK8 on Ubuntu 18.04 (also tested with Alpine Linux).

I have a `pom.xml` in the root of my project that includes my submodules :

```
...
  <modules>
    <module>mysubmodule</module>
  </modules>
...
```

In the `mysubmodule` folder, the `pom.xml` has a profile that I want to activate based on a property passed to the `mvn` executable:

```
...
    <profile>
      <id>my-profile</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>activateMyProfile</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      ...
    </profile>
...
```

I then execute mvn to start the build, but the profile is never activated:

- If I run `mvn -DactivateMyProfile release:prepare` from the root of my project, the profile is never activated and never runs
- If I run `mvn release:prepare` from the root of my project, the profile is never run.

I also tried the inverse:

```
...
    <profile>
      <id>my-profile</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>!doNotActivateMyProfile</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      ...
    </profile>
...
```

- If I run `mvn -DdoNotActivateMyProfile release:prepare` from the root of my project, the profile is still executed
- If I run `mvn release:prepare` from the root of my project, the profile is also executed

It looks like `mvn` is not able to see the properties being passed through the command line. What is the correct way to activate a profile in a submodule using a property?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of profile this is and more important why do you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am using the maven release plugin, parameters must be passed using the `-Darguments` argument.

For example, instead of using `mvn -DactivateMyProfile release:prepare`, the correct invocation is: `mvn -Darguments=-DactivateMyProfile release:prepare`

If there are multiple arguments, use `mvn -Darguments="-DactivateMyProfile -DsomeOtherArg -DanotherArg=something" release:prepare`